# How do i echo variable inside html

Tags: php, variables

I have an html image-background code which I like to output `$cartTotal` in it. My problem is: how do I echo variable `$cartTotal` inside the html code?

I have tried:

```
<?php echo'<TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0"> <TR> <TD WIDTH="60" HEIGHT="70" BACKGROUND="inventory_images/3.jpg" VALIGN="bottom"> <FONT SIZE="+5" COLOR="red"><?php
echo "$cartTotal";
?></FONT></TD> </TR> </TABLE>'; ?>
```

But it returns `$cartTotal` instead of the expected output.

Comment: Have you ever heard about punctuation marks?

Comment: No need to capitalise your HTML, it just makes it harder to type for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write `PHP` inside `PHP`. change your code to:

```
<?php echo'<TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0"> <TR> <TD WIDTH="60"
 HEIGHT="70" BACKGROUND="inventory_images/3.jpg" VALIGN="bottom"> <FONT SIZE="+5" 
COLOR="red">'.$cartTotal.'</FONT></TD> </TR> </TABLE>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

`echo` inside `echo` will not work, Just put variable name inside `echo`

```
<?php 
 echo '<TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0"> 
       <TR>
          <TD WIDTH="60" HEIGHT="70" BACKGROUND="inventory_images/3.jpg" VALIGN="bottom"> 
              <FONT SIZE="+5" COLOR="red">'.$cartTotal.'</FONT>
          </TD> 
       </TR> 
       </TABLE>'; 
?>
```

Also check some other example : https://eval.in/868385

Answer (score 2):

```html
<TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0"> 
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="60" HEIGHT="70" BACKGROUND="inventory_images/3.jpg" VALIGN="bottom"> 
<FONT SIZE="+5" COLOR="red">  
<?php echo $cartTotal; ?> 
</FONT>
</TD>
</TR> 
</TABLE>
```

Try this code:

Answer (score 1):

This might work. You have not closed the single quote, so closing the quote, and concatenating the variable (using the dot) should have the desired result.

```
<?php echo '<TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0"> <TR> <TD WIDTH="60" HEIGHT="70" BACKGROUND="inventory_images/3.jpg" VALIGN="bottom"> <FONT SIZE="+5" COLOR="red">' . $cartTotal . '</FONT></TD> </TR> </TABLE>'; ?>
```

Alternatively, you could put normal HTML with just the short-tag echo statement:

```
<TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0"> 
<TR> <TD WIDTH="60" HEIGHT="70" BACKGROUND="inventory_images/3.jpg" VALIGN="bottom"> <FONT SIZE="+5" COLOR="red">  
<?=$cartTotal?> 
</FONT></TD> </TR> </TABLE>
```

Comment: The better solution as it looks a lot cleaner. Echoing out HTML is just asking for spaghetti code. +1

Comment: @b. Desai This isnt good for me i thing i need a better image backgroud code for php hearing a variable

Comment: Do you mean: "I would like to include the cart total as part of the image background"?

Answer (score 0):

**You Can try this**

```
<?php
echo"<TABLE BORDER='0' cellpadding='0' CELLSPACING='0'>";
echo"<TR>";

echo"<TD WIDTH='60' HEIGHT='70' BACKGROUND='inventory_images/3.jpg' VALIGN='bottom'> ";
echo"<TD WIDTH='60' HEIGHT='70' BACKGROUND='inventory_images/3.jpg' VALIGN='bottom'> ";
echo $cartTotal;
echo"</FONT></TD> </TR> </TABLE> "; ?>
```

Your problem is that you are echoing inside of a single quoted string which doesn't work.